# java : Intelligent text splitting

Tags: java, clojure, split, nlp

I have some sentences like : united states of america, key with ring,

I wish to split all sentences on spaces but intelligently such that, 
united states of america becomes : "united" "states" "of america"
key with ring : "key" "with ring"
queen of beijing : "queen" "of beijing"

Do we have some library in java/clojure/scala for such splitting ?
Or any algorithm wihch could help with this.

Comment: Why don't you just split normally, and then combine two words if the first word is a function word? That will take care of all your examples ("of", "america" --> "of america", etc.).

Comment: I am not good at english, so wanted a library to do this. can we define function words to be a set of some limited words??

Comment: Yes, function words are a limited set of words, and you can download a list of function words. I have provided more details in the answer.

Comment: In what way exactly is it "intelligent" to group nouns with prepositions? And what does that mean for other types of function words, for relative clauses, for adverbial clauses, for complex noun phrases etc.? What exactly is the goal?

Comment: I have lots of data, containing nations name, cities name, brands name, I wish to create tag cloud of these. i don' want "of" or "with" to have biggest weight.

Comment: Data is mixture of titles of different things.

Comment: What you need, then, is a stop-word/function-word removal step followed by either a simple tf-idf weighting or (more sophisticated approach) topic modeling. Details on these two are beyond the scope of your current question, though.

Comment: By the way, what you are now saying in the comments is very different (and almost the opposite!) of what the examples in your question suggest.

Comment: Some times stop words are useful, as in united states of america, now i don' want it to be united states america.

Comment: Please read up on "named entity recognition". That seems to be what you really need. It is an entire field of research by itself, and is certainly much, much more complex than word splitting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no ready made library that will perform this. There is, however, a simple method to achieve the goal!

First, we need to know ***function words***, which don't have much semantic meaning of their own, but are important for grammatical and structural relationships. Some function words are "of", "about", "my", etc. For more details, please consult the following resources:

1. [The Wikipedia page on Function Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word)
2. [Function Words (pdf slides from New York Univ.)](http://www.psych.nyu.edu/pylkkanen/Neural_Bases/13_Function_Words.pdf)

The Wikipedia page also has an external link from where you can download a list of function words in English.

Once that list is obtained, we can simply use an ordinary word-splitter, and then combine one word *w_k* with the following word *w_(k+1)* if *w_k* is a function word. This approach will achieve the following results:

- "United States of America" ==> "United", "States", "of America"
- "Dark Knight of Gotham" ==> "Dark", "Knight", "of Gotham"
- "key with rings" ==> "key", "with rings"

For more sophisticated grouping of words, we need to move beyond "splitting", and venture into the territory of shallow parsing. Phrase chunking, in particular, can be very helpful in this case. Consider, for example, *Capital of the United States of America*, word splitting as above will yield "capital", "of the united", "states", "of america" ... which is probably not desirable. Phrase chunking, on the other hand will yield

```
[Capital]  [of]  [the United States]  [of]  [America]
```

Now, we can join the prepositions (if that is required) to the subsequent phrase to obtain

```
[Capital] [of the United States] [of America]
```

A good phrase chunking program is made available by the cognitive computing group at Univ. of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, including an [online demo](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/shallowparse/?id=7).

Comment: "Capital of the United States" will be split into "Capital", "of the United", and "States". Is that what the OP expects to get?

Comment: Agreed. But then, splitting can only be "intelligent" up to a certain point. Beyond that, one would have to start looking into machine learning algorithms (specifically, some sort of Markov chain based paradigm).

Comment: In light of your example, added some info on phrase chunking, in case that's what OP needs. But this being NLP, there will always be counterexamples to even the most sophisticated approach!

Comment: can i somehow identify that "of the united states" is same as "united states" ? again i will have to compare terms apart from function words.. ??

Comment: You can just remove function words to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. +1